# Some problems in Noncommutative Algebra book of Benson Farb and R. Keith Dennis

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains, division-ring

In [this, page 48, Exercies in chapter 1](http://library.lol/main/6A72B4E379381CA2483A121D920F699E), there is a following exercise.

**Exercise 2.** Let $R$ be a ring (with $1$) such that the only left ideals of $R$ are $0$ and $R.$ Show that $R$ must be a division ring; that is, if $R$ is simple as a left $R$-module, then $R$ is a division ring. If the hypothesis that $R$ has an identity is dropped, the result no longer holds. Give an example to show this. In fact, the type of example you give is unique.

I have written a little about it. Regard a ring $R$ as an $R$-module.     If $R$ is simple, we will show that $R$ is a divison ring. Indeed, if $x\in R,$ then $R=Rx,$ and so there is $y\in R$ such that $yx=1.$ Since $y$ is an element of the simple $R$-module $R,$ we have $R=Ry.$ This implies $1=zy.$ Moreover, $z=z1=z(yx)=(zy)x=1x=x.$ Therefore $R$ is a division ring. Otherwise, if $R$ is a division ring, then we will show that $R$ is simple. Indeed, if $x\in R,$ then $Rx$ is a submodule of $R.$ It seems that $R=Rx.$ This implies $R$ is a division ring.

The rest of the problem leaves me wondering. In this book, the ring is defined by a ring, has certainly identity $1.$ But the author gives $1$ and finds an example about the division ring without $1.$ I think the definition of a division ring requires $1.$ Moreover, I can't find an example about it.

Other way, in exercises 4 (c) and 4 (d),  I think that $\mathbf{Q}$ must be written $\mathbf{Q}[x],$ and all simple $R$-modules, where $R$ is a principal ideal domain, are isomorphic to $R/I$ where $I$ is an ideal generated by a irreducible element. I'm not sure about this.

Please take a look and help me.

Comment: Although the OP linked question was misstated, the solutions address everything you're asking about.  The author is not asking about *a division ring without 1* he is asking about *a ring with trivial right ideals and no 1*.  As in the linked post, $\mathbb Z/(p)$ with multiplication defined to be uniformly zero furnishes an example.

Comment: If you want to ask about 4c and 4d, do so in a separate question. When you make your post a laundry list of exercises, its quality decreases dramatically and it will likely be closed for improvement.  Also take your time to type out what you are asking about instead of using links to weird websites.